# How to setup the Spark-Cassandra connector to connect to Cassandra cluster on Kubernetes

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes-ingress, spark-cassandra-connector, k8ssandra

We are getting pretty bad write performance using the Spark-Cassandra connector, when Cassandra is on k8s.
For clarity -
we're trying to write a DF with 1.3Bn unique keys (around 30GB)
with 16 executors, each with 4 cores and 16GB memory.
we have a Cassandra cluster of 5 Nodes (replication factor = 2), where the cassandra table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE <tablename> (hashed_id text PRIMARY KEY, timestamp1 bigint, timestamp2 bigint)
```

The write took around 8 hours....

Sample code of how we write a DataFrame to Cassandra:

```
df
.write
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.mode("overwrite")
.option("confirm.truncate", "true")
.options(table=tablename, keyspace=cassandra_keyspace)
.save()
```

We've recently started using Cassandra, and decided it will be deployed on Kubernetes.
We are running some ETLs on Spark that need to write directly to Cassandra.

Our setup is:

- Cassandra (4.0) deployed on k8s using K8ssandra operator (1.6), behind a traefik ingress (no TLS)
- Spark (3.2) deployed on bare-metal, ETLs in Pyspark, using [spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.2.0](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/releases/tag/v3.2.0).

Im looking for any reference on how to configure the spark connector to use all nodes in a such a case.
What Im assuming is happening, is that the connector is only able to "see" the ingress address and gets back internal IPs for the other nodes.
we want to follow the examples [here](https://github.com/k8ssandra/cass-operator/tree/master/docs/ingress/sample-java-application) but not sure how we could configure the spark connector to use such configurations...

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions,

1. Why the writes are taking longer?
2. It is not very clear to me what role SCC has in the K8s ingress.

To answer question #1,

- `spark.cassandra.connection.resolveContactPoints` when set to `true` (Default)    Controls, if we need to resolve contact points at start (true), or at reconnection (false). Helpful for usage with Kubernetes or other systems with dynamic endpoints which may change while the application is running. Ensure you haven't set it to `false`.
- `spark.cassandra.coonection.host` - The hosts given here will be used as an intial contact point to the C* cluster. Upon getting the initial connection, it would find the entire topology of the cluster.

SCC Configuration Parameters are available [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md). You can tune in the `Write Tuning Parameters` i.e. the ones starting with `spark.cassandra.output.*`. Also, ensure your C* cluster is properly sized (e.g. hardware specs, datamodel, etc.,) to run efficiently.

Comment: thanks for the answer!
For your first point - the problem when connecting to a Cassandra cluster that is running on k8s, from outside the cluster, is that (depending on your setup) you will get the nodes in the cluster with their internal k8s IPs - that are not accessible from the outside.
That is why in the Java Driver Datastax offer some options to add address translation on the client side to avoid marking all nodes with internal ips as DOWN. Im trying to figure out if there's a similar way to do it for the Spark Connector